# I need the SQLite equivalent of MySQL for working with unix timestamps

Tags: android, sqlite, unix-timestamp

I'm using unix timestamps with SQLite and storing them as an integer. My problem is that I am trying to select records for today based on their unix timestamps and I have no clue what functions to use.

Here is what I would use in MySQL:

`where date_format(from_unixtime(COLUMN_DATE), '%Y-%m-%d')= date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')`

However when I try to use these functions I'm getting errors in the log telling me they don't exist for SQLite.

How do I write this for SQLite?

Comment: read sqlite documentation ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQLite date and time functions are documented at http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html.

The equivalent of your `WHERE` clause would be

```
WHERE date(COLUMN_DATE,'unixepoch') = date('now')
```

Comment: Shouldn't you ignore the time portion of the timestamp?

Comment: `date` function does it for me (we use `datetime` to get time *and* date)

Comment: i was using datetime = date before and it wasnt working. now i know why. thanks alot.