# How to sort table row based on Specific Column and Month in Android SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, unix-timestamp

My Table Look Like this:

```
_id         amount      merchant                category    date        note
15          50000       Mithu Roy               Maintenanc  1473825600  Android
18          7852        efefefwe                Bills       1474084800  efeffwf
21          463         trhth                   Bills       1473912000  thth
```

**I want to calculate the total amount depending upon the month.**

*Problems:*

1. Dates are in Unix Timestamp.
2. I've no idea how to get just the month from the **UNIX timestamp** that's why I can't query the database to get all the month-specific amounts.

Comment: Check following links:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500527/select-current-months-records-mysql-from-timestamp-column and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775012/i-need-the-sqlite-equivalent-of-mysql-for-working-with-unix-timestamps

Comment: pls go through this [site](http://www.epochconverter.com/) you may get answers

Comment: Hi, @Anil
From this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500527/select-current-months-records-mysql-from-timestamp-column) I found this code
`SELECT id, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampfield) timestamp 
  FROM table1
 WHERE timestampfield >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
   AND timestampfield <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY);`
**But it's not working with Android SQLite**

Comment: You checked this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775012/i-need-the-sqlite-equivalent-of-mysql-for-working-with-unix-timestamps

Comment: I checked this link before, the problem is I can get the current date but there's no way I can extract the month. If I extract the whole date then I have to process these data in my code itself and get the month and then again query the database to get the month specific amount, it's a multi process system, but I wanted something simple so I can just extract the month directly using SQL and do the query. @Anil

Comment: try this query `select * from your_table_name where strftime('%m',date(date,'unixepoch'))=='09'`